# Separating Date and Time values from SQL Server 2008 to display in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime

I have a database table that stores a datetime value.
I want to display that value on my asp.net textboxes, except I need to show date value in TextBox A and Time in TextBox B.

How can I split those values in VB.NET?

Comment: Please post your code. The question is very unclear and code samples will make it much clearer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is to use format string:

- Date: `dateTimeReadedFromDb.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")`
- Time: `dateTimeReadedFromDb.ToString("hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: I get a green squiggly line saying "Runtime errors might occur when converting 'String' to 'System. IFormatProvider' "

Comment: better yet.... I get an error message "Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IFormatProvider'"

Comment: DateValue = DateTime.Parse(FromDate.Value).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in date formatting functions in VB:

```
Dim ThisDate as DateTime = Now

Dim TimePart as string = ThisDate.ToShortTimeString
dim DatePart as string = ThisDate.ToShortDateString
```